# Extract Email ID, Mobile phone, sipaddress ,other attributes from PeoplePicker Field in SP 2010 CustomList NewForm

Tags: 2010, spservices, people-picker

After referring [this](http://sympmarc.com/2008/05/08/get-a-people-pickers-current-value-on-a-form/) article from Marc,
and [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144467/get-values-from-sharepoint-clientpeoplepicker-using-jquery/164288#164288) 
 am able to get/perform the null check for peoplepicker entries in my custom `newform` of my SPList within SP Designer 2010.
 But, how to retrieve other attributes, like, if i want to get the email id, display name and other details from this ?

I displayed

```
> alert( innerSpans[0].innerHTML  +  ' is  0th index');
```

> ---
>
> Message from webpage
>
> ---

```
 <DIV id=divEntityData style="DISPLAY: none" description="mydomain\p_p" 
    isresolved="True" displaytext="P P" key="i:0#.w|mydomain\p_">
      <DIV data='<ArrayOfDictionaryEntry                 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Email</Key><Value 
         xsi:type="xsd:string">
        P_p@mydomian.com</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key 
       xsi:type="xsd:string">MobilePhone
     </Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">+91 98 2726 7723</Value>
        </DictionaryEntry>
         <DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Department</Key>
        <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">mfg</Value></DictionaryEntry>
         <DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">
       SIPAddress</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">
        P_p@mydomain.com
      </Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry>
      <Key xsi:type="xsd:string">
    Title</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/></DictionaryEntry>
      </ArrayOfDictionaryEntry>'></DIV></DIV>
```

and i got above details, but I am stuck with how to extract those
  DictionaryEntry from DictionaryEntryArray.

How to iterate through the array of DictionaryEntryArray items.

```
function getPickerInputElement(identifier) 
{
 alert('  inside getPickerInputElement ');
   alert(identifier);
 var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
  for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++) {
 var tempString = tags[i].id;
 //alert('tags[' + i + '].id = ' + tempString);
  if ((tempString.indexOf(identifier) > 0) && 
   (tempString.indexOf('UserField_upLevelDiv') > 0)){
   //alert('HIT for ' + identifier + ' id=' + tags[i].id + ' value=' + 
   tags[i].value);
 var innerSpans = tags[i].getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
for(var j=0; j < innerSpans.length; j++) {
 //alert('innerSpans[' + j + '].id = ' + innerSpans[j].id);
 if(innerSpans[j].id == 'content') 
 {
  //alert('HIT for ' + identifier + ' id=' + innerSpans[j].id + ' 
   innerHTML=' + innerSpans[j].innerHTML);
  alert( innerSpans[0].innerHTML  +  ' is  0th index');
  return innerSpans[j].innerHTML;
   }    }     }  }
return null; }
 </script>
```

i tried to get the value below:

```
 var pp2 = $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({  peoplePickerDisplayName: 
         whatDisplayName }).row.find("div[id='divEntityData']")
      .attr("displaytext");
```

so i got the correct value of displayname.
 But similarly, how to get the other  attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution with SPServices is just ok. You should use jQuery to parse data and you could use selectors:

```
var picker = $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
   peoplePickerDisplayName: whatDisplayName //your picker control field's display name
});

var data = picker.row.find("div[id='divEntityData'] div").attr("data");

var xml = $(data);//accepting data by jQuery

var data = xml.find('Key:contains("MobilePhone")').next().text();
console.log(data);//data contains mobile phone now
```

Comment: Without testing on my end, this looks like the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below link as a reference and which gives you all attributes belongs to a user:

[Get all attributes from user](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation)